# Symfony Unit tests failing on Travis CI

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, travis-ci, symfony-3.4

I'm creating a Symfony 3.4 application.
Then I started to write some tests, which totally pass locally :

```
/**
  * Two steps :
  * 1) Checks if page goes on 200 status
  * 2) Posts sample datas
  */
    public function testDistanceAmongSequencesAction()
    {
        /**
         * 1 - Access to the page OK
         */
        $this->client->request('GET', '/minitools/distance-among-sequences');
        static::assertEquals(200, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    }
```

But when I push my code and execute it with Travis CI, it fails automatically : 3) MinitoolsBundleTest\Controller\MinitoolsControllerTest::testDistanceAmongSequencesAction
Failed asserting that 500 matches expected 200.

He is my .travis.yml file :

```
language: php
sudo: required
dist: trusty

php:
  - '7.1.16'

services:
  - mysql

script:
  - composer self-update
  - composer install --no-interaction --no-suggest
  - bin/console server:run &
  - vendor/bin/phpunit
```

The PHP version is the same as mine. I think the VM Travis can't access to y path, but why ? Thank you for your help !

Comment: Add some logs from travis, there should be information whet is wrong

Comment: Thanks, how can I do that ?

Comment: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/running-build-in-debug-mode/

Comment: Maybe you should run migrations before tests?

Comment: I dont' have migrations for the moment, the URLs I'm testing haven't any connection to the database.

Comment: I see. This is a problem with TWIG :

[2019-07-24 09:28:16] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Twig\Error\LoaderError: "Unable to find template "@Minitools/Minitools/skews.html.twig"

But i don't understand : it works perfectely on my server, and locally doing tests ...

Comment: Well, I'll try centralising the templates and not using the @ annotation ... thanks for the tipp !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, in my controller I called the TWIG templates using @ annotation, and Travis doesn't understand it. So I modified each call and moved the TWIG into app/ressources. Thanks.